# Is It Impossible To Change SSDL Content In The Running Or The Compile Time (Visual Studio 2015 EntityFramework Database First With Oracle )

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I do have a serious problem with SSDL content,is it impossible to change SSDL content because I have a lot of different DB locations like as following picture

[image]

so that when I use EntityFramework (Database First) with CRUD like as following code ,could I change it like from **HTCE6** to **TESTE6** etc..

[image]

> by the way , I have traced the T-SQL script like as following code , I
>   wish I can modify from "HTCE6"."PSI_QUOTE_DT" to other DB like
>   "*****"."PSI_QUOTE_DT"

```
insert into "HTCE6"."PSI_QUOTE_DT"("COMP_COD", "ORDER_NOS", "ORDER_SER", "GOODS_COD", "TAX_TYP", "UNIT_AMT", "UNIT_TYP", "UNIT_NOS", "SALE_AMT", "ITEM_QNT", "DISC_RAT", "SORDER_AMT", "SORDER_TAX", "ORDER_RMK", "GIFT_FLAG", "REMAIN_QNT", "REG_AMT", "SUPLY_COD", "PURCH_AMT", "FLAG1_STA", "TRPRICE_COD", "TRANS_NOS", "TRANS_TYP", "WHOUSE_COD")
values (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10, :p11, :p12, null, :p13, :p14, null, null, :p15, :p16, :p17, null, null, :p18)
```

Please do me a favour even if a little bit slight cubes ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has tried to be finished this issue , it isn't very good idea however it can be temperate to deal with my problem, hopefully it is another way to handle my question as like my picture ,it is without insert any DB name
[image]

PS:Please give me more any good methods or ideas if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi it will be useful for your problems 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387152(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: sorry , this information isn't enough to deal with my problems